# Regex for all spaces that not surrounded by quotes

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to write a regex that matches all spaces except those enclosed in quotes.
I found solutions on the Internet for various programming languages, for example, [here](https://regex101.com/r/5I209k/4), but I am having trouble converting this to Vim regex:

```
\s(?=(?:[^'"`]*(['"`])[^'"`]*\1)*[^'"`]*$)
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please [edit] to include the specific regular expression you're having trouble translating (and its flavor, if you know it). Having links is a great bonus, but we want the question to stand on its own even if the links die.

Comment: Thank you! I had a link to regex101 before, but it doesn't seem to be very noticeable, I duplicated the regex in the post too.

Comment: the regex is not Vim Regex!

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, I know, it's ECMA Script Regex. And I need to convert it to Vim Regex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positive look-ahead `(?=` is `\@=` in Vim regex, non-capturing groups are `\%(\)` and capturing-groups are `\(\)`. That would make your pattern:

```
\s\%(\%([^'"`]*\(['"`]\)[^'"`]*\1\)*[^'"`]*$\)\@=
```

There is a nice summary for comparing Perl compatible patterns with Vims in the help [:h perl-patterns](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#perl-patterns):

| Capability | in Vimspeak | in Perlspeak |
| --- | --- | --- |
| force case insensitivity | `\c` | `(?i)` |
| force case sensitivity | `\C` | `(?-i)` |
| backref-less grouping | `\%(atom\)` | `(?:atom)` |
| conservative quantifiers | `\{-n,m}` | `*?, +?, ??, {}?` |
| 0-width match | `atom\@=` | `(?=atom)` |
| 0-width non-match | `atom\@!` | `(?!atom)` |
| 0-width preceding match | `atom\@<=` | `(?<=atom)` |
| 0-width preceding non-match | `atom\@<!` | `(?<!atom)` |
| match without retry | `atom\@>` | `(?>atom)` |

That helps translating patterns.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Did not know about `:h perl-patterns:`!

I have a related question. If I put this into the following function: `echo split('text "text"', "\\s\\%(\\%([^'\"\`]*\\(['\"\`]\\)[^'\"\`]*\\1\\)*[^'\"\`]*$\\)\\@=")`, I will have the following results: `['text', '"text"']` (double quotes captured). But if I use this expression in search (`/`), then the quotes are not captured. Can I avoid quotes capturing?

Comment: you are splitting on that regex. That means, all non-matches will be kept in your list.